# Devise after :confirmable on ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

After the user confirms his account, when he clicks in the link sent to his email, he automatically signs in. How can I disable this characteristic? is it possible?

Comment: Which version of devise are you using?  In 3.1 and later, the default is for the user *not* to be logged in, unless you have `config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true` in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

Comment: well, yes you were right, just updated from 2.2.4 to 3.2.4. I restarted the server, but the user still logs in the project automatically. Is there anything else should I do?

Comment: If you definitely haven't got `config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true` in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, then it would be useful to know the relevant devise routes in you project and whether you've customised/overridden any of devise's controllers/views.

Comment: Glad it works.  Your issue with tokens may be related (see the part of my answer about digested tokens if it was a token that existed before your devise upgrade) or it may be unrelated, in which case this question I answered a while ago might be of use if you are using an `after_create` callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567625/devise-confirmation-invalid-on-first-send/21917636 -- otherwise it would be best to raise a new question with more details on your problem, info from log etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the default behaviour in versions of devise before 3.1 and as far as I know there is no trivial way to change it.  I think you would need to override devise's `ConfirmationsController`.

The behaviour changed in 3.1, so that the default is that the user is *not* logged in after using the confirmation link.  If you wanted to retain the old behaviour of logging in, you would need to have `config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true` in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

As discussed in the comments, upgrading from devise 2.2.4 to 3.2.4 resulted in the behaviour changing to be what you wanted.

Devise 3.1 introduced a number of other security-related changes.  More information is available here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/

Note that one of the other changes in 3.1 was that confirmation/reset/unlock tokens are stored digested in the database, so previously-stored tokens won't work unless you set `config.allow_insecure_token_lookup = true` in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, ideally temporarily so users who just requested a token can use it but after removal of this line all future lookups will assume digested tokens are in the db.  See the above link for more detail.